# Can't use the Virtual Stick even though isVirtualStickControlModeAvailable returns true

Tags: swift3, dji-sdk

I am having a problem with the virtual sticks, the following is the problem.

The Virtual sticks fire the notification, the listener sends the proper values to the roll, pitch, yaw and throttle, the [isVirtualStickControlModeAvailable](https://developer.dji.com/api-reference/ios-api/Components/FlightController/DJIFlightController.html?search=virtual&i=2&#djiflightcontroller_virtualstickcontrolmodecategory_isvirtualstickcontrolmodeavailable_inline) method from the sdk returns true, when it returns true I use the command from the flight controller [send](https://developer.dji.com/api-reference/ios-api/Components/FlightController/DJIFlightController.html?search=virtual&i=2&#djiflightcontroller_senddatatoonboardsdkdevice_inline) which returns the completion error nil, which means I can not do anything else from there, actually I do not need to do anything else. The virtual Sticks are working in a timer as the sample [simulator](https://developer.dji.com/mobile-sdk/documentation/ios-tutorials/SimulatorDemo.html) from DJI.

What can I do in my app?
 - Take off
 - Land
 - Give control back and forward to the RC

None of the list above brings me errors, including the process of the virtualStick.

What else did I try?
 - Run the sample simulator app from DJI, linked above.
 - Run the sample app on Android
 - Run using the Bridge APP (Thats how i know the values are being passed correctly, even though i added labels on screen to debug without the Bridge APP)
 - Update firmware from the aircraft and RC to the latest
 - Sample simulator IOS
 - Went back to previous working commits and branches on git

None of the things I have tried above worked.

Curious Stuf:
 - The virtual Sticks worked fine till Yesterday, and before yesterday, in many diferent branches and commits in multiple branches.
 - Reseting the Remote control, Executing Manual Linking and Linking through the DJI Official APP, and clearing the cache, memory sdcard made it work on Simulator Assistent DJI (Latest version) with a lot of interference, in the Sample apps on Android and IOS, and on my Swift 3 application. Then it had some interference, I tested outside on the real Aircraft, it was working beautifully.
 - Today, the same thing happens. Already did the whole testing above mentioned, the Android sample apps, IOS Sample Apps, the Simulator, Bridge, My application, Reset remote etc. And it does not work.

I would be really glad if someone could point me out the problem.

On this thread I explain partially the problem and what I have tried. http://forum.dev.dji.com/forum.php?mod=viewthread&tid=32729

Already sent an email to DJI support, still no answer.

Aircraft: Phanton 4.

Comment: Is your RC in P mode when you are trying this?

Comment: @aksh1t Yes, i did try all the modes.

Comment: Also i the documentation says, a frequency of 10hz, I am sending the values of the sticks in this frequency.

Answer (score 1):

I have found the problem, it was the aircraft, I could get hands in a new aircraft, just pluged to the new RC linked to the new Aircraft, it worked with no problem.
Then I tested the new RC linking to the old aircraft, It did not work, then the Old RC with linked to the new Aircraft, it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Glad you found the fix.
It might be worth it to update the firmware of the old aircraft.
You can do so using the DJIGo app or DJI Assistant software for desktop.